# Groupby with TimeGrouper 'backwards'

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, time-series

I have a `DataFrame` containing a time series:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2016-06-01', periods=24*7, freq='H')
ones = pd.Series([1]*24*7, rng)
rdf = pd.DataFrame({'a': ones})
```

Last entry is `2016-06-07 23:00:00`. I now want to group this by, say two days, basically like so:

```
rdf.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('2D')).sum()
```

However, I want to group starting from my last data point backwards, so instead of getting this result:

```
            a
2016-06-01  48
2016-06-03  48
2016-06-05  48
2016-06-07  24
```

I'd much rather expect this:

```
            a
2016-06-01  24
2016-06-03  48
2016-06-05  48
2016-06-07  48
```

and when grouping by `'3D'`:

```
            a
2016-06-01  24
2016-06-04  72
2016-06-07  72
```

Expected outcome when grouping by `'4D'` is:

```
            a
2016-06-03  72
2016-06-07  96
```

I am not able to get this with every combination of `closed`, `label` etc. I could think of.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I primarily want to group by 7 days, aka one week, I am using this method now to come to the desired bins:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import Week

# Let's not make full weeks
hours = 24*6*4
rng = pd.date_range('2016-06-01', periods=hours, freq='H')

# Set week start to whatever the last weekday of the range is
print("Last day is %s" % rng[-1])
freq = Week(weekday=rng[-1].weekday())

ones = pd.Series([1]*hours, rng)
rdf = pd.DataFrame({'a': ones})
rdf.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq=freq, closed='right', label='right')).sum()
```

This gives me the desired output of

```
2016-06-25  96
2016-07-02  168
2016-07-09  168
```

Comment: This can probably be done more generically with ```DateOffset``` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question now focuses on grouping by week, you can simply:

```
rdf.resample('W-{}'.format(rdf.index[-1].strftime('%a')), closed='right', label='right').sum()
```

You can use `loffset` to get it to work - at least for most periods (using `.resample()`):

```
for i in range(2, 7):
    print(i)
    print(rdf.resample('{}D'.format(i), closed='right', loffset='{}D'.format(i)).sum())

2
             a
2016-06-01  24
2016-06-03  48
2016-06-05  48
2016-06-07  48
3
             a
2016-06-01  24
2016-06-04  72
2016-06-07  72
4
             a
2016-06-01  24
2016-06-05  96
2016-06-09  48
5
              a
2016-06-01   24
2016-06-06  120
2016-06-11   24
6
              a
2016-06-01   24
2016-06-07  144
```

However, you could also create custom groupings that calculate the correct values without `TimeGrouper` like so:

```
days = rdf.index.to_series().dt.day.unique()[::-1]
for n in range(2, 7):
    chunks = [days[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(days), n)][::-1]
    grp = pd.Series({k: v for d in [zip(chunk, [idx] * len(chunk)) for idx, chunk in enumerate(chunks)] for k, v in d})
    rdf.groupby(rdf.index.to_series().dt.day.map(grp))['a'].sum()

 2
groups
0    24
1    48
2    48
3    48
Name: a, dtype: int64

 3
groups
0    24
1    72
2    72
Name: a, dtype: int64

 4
groups
0    72
1    96
Name: a, dtype: int64

 5
groups
0     48
1    120
Name: a, dtype: int64

 6
groups
0     24
1    144
Name: a, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks! Since the last bin is my most important one, I'd need this to be very reliable. Strange, that there seems to be no face-palm easy solution for this.

Comment: See updated for a solution to calculate the group values in a reliable way but not using TimeGrouper.