# How to do backward resampling on time series data starting from the last row?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, time-series

I have rows of data (per second) that I used to resample by two hour, and for each feature I applied different calculation, in short:

```
data = data.resample('2H').agg({'id':'first','x1': np.sum, 
                                'x2': np.mean}).dropna()
```

Since each file contains one day record, it will result in about 12 rows that start at 00:00 each day.

```
datetime            id      x1      x2      
2019/05/03 0:00     5603    1324    4600
2019/05/03 2:00     5603    1276    2836
2019/05/03 4:00     5603    184     258
2019/05/03 6:00     5603    546     929
2019/05/03 8:00     5603    2       1
2019/05/03 10:00    5603    6       3
2019/05/03 12:00    5603    8       5
2019/05/03 14:00    5603    835     1798
2019/05/03 16:00    5603    14      7
2019/05/03 18:00    5603    690     1518
2019/05/03 20:00    5603    823     1636
2019/05/03 22:00    5603    972     2547
```

My question is: how do I resample by two hours (or any time frame) backwards from the last row?
Currently, for every CSV file, the last row will be my "starting point" to resample backwards, e.g:

If my last row is 2019/05/03 09:27:00 then I need to resample the data from 2019/05/03 07:27:00 to 2019/05/03 09:27:00, and so on.

I looked for the same problem, found this: [Pandas resample time series counting backwards (or reverse resample)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51787945/pandas-resample-time-series-counting-backwards-or-reverse-resample) but not able to implement it for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by applying a transformation to your time stamp, resampling on the transformed index and then reverting the transformation.

```
end_time = data.index[-1]
data['time to end'] = end_time - data.index
data.set_index('time to end', inplace=True)

data = data.resample('2h').mean() # Or your function

data['datetime'] = end_time - data.index
data.set_index('datetime', inplace=True)
```

Comment: Got some error right here: ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 2), indices imply (1, 0), and the time to end shows NaT, any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

This was driving me crazy too. I kept feeling like resample should just do what I wanted. Ultimately I got it to work by using the **origin** parameter.

```
periods = pd.date_range("2020-10-17 15:53:03", "2020-10-17 15:56:56", freq="1s")
ts = pd.Series(range(len(periods)), index=periods)
resampled = ts.resample('60s', origin=ts.index[-1], closed='right', label='right')
```