# pandas.Grouper() returning a grouped date label outside of my data

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to group a pandas dataframe in last 7 day groups from the most recent date in my dataframe using `pd.Grouper()`.

**Why does Grouper return a label which is outside of what dates my data includes? When using `closed='right'` and `label='right'` I would think the last label in my Grouper groupby would be the most recent date in my dataframe, and include the last 7 dates worth of data which doesn't seem to be the case.**

**Real behavior**

```
import pandas as pd

df_test = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2019-05-07','2019-05-07','2019-05-06', '2019-05-05', 
                                '2019-05-04', '2019-05-03', '2019-05-01', 
                                '2019-04-28', '2019-04-28','2019-04-23',
                                '2019-04-20','2019-04-18','2019-04-15','2019-04-16'],
                        'Things':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
                       })
df_test['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_test.Date, yearfirst=True)
df_test.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date', freq='7D', label='right', closed='right')).count()
```

[image]

**Expected behavior**

[image]

## Update: Using Asmus' code snippet

and adding '2019-05-08' to my data since 2019-05-07 may have been an arbitrary even bin given the test data, I expect the latest date in the groupby to be '2019-05-08' not '2019-05-14' since I want to bin backwards 7 days from my most recent data where my label and bin start from the `right`:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2019-05-08','2019-05-07','2019-05-07','2019-05-06', '2019-05-05', '2019-05-04', '2019-05-03',  
                                '2019-05-01', '2019-04-28', '2019-04-28',
                                '2019-04-23', '2019-04-20','2019-04-18',
                                '2019-04-15','2019-04-16'],
                        'Things':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
                       })
df_test['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_test.Date, yearfirst=True)
df_test=df_test.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df_test.Date),drop=False)
df_test.resample('W-{}'.format(
        df_test.index[-1].strftime('%a')
        ), closed='right', label='right').count()
```

Produces...
[image]
instead of what I expect using closed=right and label=right which would end with the last group `2019-05-08` with Things 7, then `2019-05-01` with Things 3, etc.

But when using Asmus' timedelta adding 1 day, I'm getting the expected grouping behavior with the time group label signifying a group up to but not including '2019-05-09'. Got it :thumbsup!

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2019-05-08','2019-05-07','2019-05-07','2019-05-06', '2019-05-05', '2019-05-04', '2019-05-03',  
                                '2019-05-01', '2019-04-28', '2019-04-28',
                                '2019-04-23', '2019-04-20','2019-04-18',
                                '2019-04-15','2019-04-16'],
                        'Things':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
                       })
df_test['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_test.Date, yearfirst=True)
df_test=df_test.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df_test.Date),drop=False)
futureDay= (df_test.Date.max() + pd.Timedelta('1 days')).strftime('%a')
df_test.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='W-{}'.format(futureDay), closed='right', label='right')).count()
```

Correctly produces....
[image]

Thanks @Asmus !

Comment: `Grouper` works as expected: he splits all the data in slice of 7d and counts the number of element in each slice. `Grouper` extends the limit of date slice to the bigger one.
The result you are expecting break this rule because the last slice is larger than 7 days.

Comment: That is work correct , since you time difference is 7 d ...

Comment: Ohhhh, because it's using the latest date as if it were an index and not including that last date for that group. Now I understand why Asmus is using timedelta to add 1 day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, let's revisit your expected result upon grouping 7 days, which inherently needs to be *inclusive* of the most recent day:

```
2019-05-07       1
2019-05-07       1
2019-05-06       1
2019-05-05       1
2019-05-04       1
2019-05-03       1
2019-05-01       1
                 ## ^ group of 7, until 2019-04-30
2019-04-28       1
2019-04-28       1
                 ## ^ group of 2, until 2019-04-23
2019-04-23       1
2019-04-20       1
2019-04-18       1
                 ## ^ group of 3, until 2019-04-16
2019-04-16       1
2019-04-15       1
                 ## ^ group of 2, the remainder
```

A solution for this grouping can be [found in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37887371/565489), if you first set a "proper" index:

```py
df_test=df_test.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df_test.Date),drop=False)

print( df_test.resample('W-{}'.format(
        df_test.index[-1].strftime('%a')
        ), closed='right', label='right').sum() )
```

which yields:

```
            Things
Date              
2019-04-16       2
2019-04-23       3
2019-04-30       2
2019-05-07       7
```

Or, for the sake of completeness, if you'd e.g. rather sample backwards from *one day into the future* of your latest entry, and want to use a d `pd.Grouper()`, that'd be:

```py
futureDay= (df_test.Date.max() + pd.Timedelta('1 days') ).strftime('%a')
print( df_test.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='W-{}'.format(futureDay), 
                                  closed='right', label='right')).sum() )
```

Comment: maybe my data was a bad example because 2019-05-07 ends up being an even 7 split. When I add another date 2019-05-08 the latest week ending is 2019-05-14 even though I expect it to be 2019-05-08 since I want count back 7 days from 2019-05-08 and of course, 05-24 isn't included in the count back.

Comment: added my understanding of your Timedelta solution which is the solution I'm looking for. Thanks!